# Could not initialize DateTimePicker without an input element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

Using Bootstrap datetimepicker with the bootstrap editable. previously it  showing the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseFormat' of undefined for removing this error replace text in bootstrap-editable.js,

```
this.dpg = $.fn.datetimepicker.DPGlobal; and change it to this.dpg = $.fn.bdatepicker.DPGlobal;
```

but now its showing error Uncaught Error: Could not initialize DateTimePicker without an input element

```
<a href="#" id="last_seen" data-type="datetime" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" title="Select date & time">15/03/2013 12:45</a>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#last_seen').editable({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',    
        viewformat: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii',    
        datetimepicker: {
                weekStart: 1
           }
    });
});
</script>
```